# Capturar todos los eventos de los elementos "a" con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

¡Buenos días!

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web y tengo una duda la cual es si es posible poder capturar, en javascript, todos los eventos que generan los elementos "a" (<a href=...), ya que necesitamos tratar los enlaces que llevan, porque en función del que lleve, la aplicación se deberá de comportar de una forma o de otra. Nuestra aplicación tiene muchos elementos "a" y casi la mayoría no tienen identificador ninguno.
Espero poder haberme explicado y poder recibir algún tipo de ayuda al respecto.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el código que has intentado?

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. Pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las contestaciones.

Pongo aquí la solución que me ha funcionado a mí por si a alguien le puede valer:

```
var a1 = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (a2 of a1) {
    a2.addEventListener("click", function(evento){
        var variable = evento.target;
        console.log("Texto del enlace:", variable.innerText);
        console.log("Texto del href:", variable.href);
   });
}
```

Lo que hago en este código es simple, recupero todos los elementos "a" del documento y me quedo con el que han "cliqueado", posteriormente a través del evento obtengo el innerText y el href que es lo que me hacía falta.

Nuevamente gracias a todos.

Comment: Explica brevemente el funcionamiento de tu código: ten en cuenta que otros usuarios puede que vean tu respuesta y no comprendan su funcionamiento. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.